# POST and GET result whit jQuery and php error

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send an get data from this way and creat input whit this jquery
and post to php page and get result
but the problem is :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

**jQuery**

```
$('#ss').live('click', function () {
    $("#main_login").html("<center>waiting plaese . . . .</center>");
    var arr = $("#myInputs").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: "myInputs=" + arr,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#main_login').html(data)
        }

    });
});


$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;


    $('#text').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><input type="text" id="myInputs" size="20" name="myInputs[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> <a href="#" id="rtext">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="text">add</a><br>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="myInputs[]" size="20" name="myInputs[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label></p>
<div id="main_login"></div>
```

php

```
$name = $_POST['myInputs'];
foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {
    print "The name is ".$n." and email is , thank you<br>";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `$_POST['myinputs']` isn't populated or isn't an array.

Comment: but it work when i use form

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST['myInputs']);` and share the output here?

Comment: output :string(4) "test"   and some error

Comment: A string is not a valid input for a foreach statement.

Comment: No need to use Id as myInputs[] it should be myInputs

Comment: If it's working with form then why are you not using it?

Comment: Because i need to get jquery functions from result and in form method i cant get jquery functions (i dont know actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your javascript, not the PHP. These lines:

```
var arr = $("#myInputs").val();
[...]
    data: "myInputs=" + arr,
```

**Problems**

1. Because you're using a CSS ID selector you're only allowed one element with that ID
2. `$("#myInputs").val()` will only return the value of the first element, and it will be a string, not an array
3. `"myInputs=" + arr` will send the POST data as a string, not an array

**Solutions**

You need to do a couple things to fix these issues:

1. Switch `id='myInputs[]'` to use a CSS class (i.e. `class='myInputs'`)
2. Pull all values from the `.myInputs` elements and combine them in an array (hint: use [jQuery's .each function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/))
3. Change `"myInputs="` to array format (i.e. `{ "myInputs[]" : arr }`)

Let me show you:

**HTML**

```
    <p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="myInputs" size="20" name="myInputs[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#ss').live('click', function () {
    $("#main_login").html("<center>waiting plaese . . . .</center>");
    var arr = [];
    $(".myInputs").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: { "myInputs[]" : arr },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#main_login').html(data)
        }
    });
});
```